# how to get the corresponding id of the row in display tag

Tags: java, javascript, servlets, displaytag

I have a displaytag to display results. But in this displaytag, I want the corresponding occid of the row. But I don't know due to some problem, it is showing me the id of the first row only. It works as follows-
when i enter a name and click on search , it goes to a servlet which fetches the details and shows in the displaytag. Since i want to edit the details, what I do here is I click on the radio button of a row and click on edit button. The edit button will take the occid and send it to another servlet for futher processing.

```
      <display:table name="requestScope.List" export="true" class="displaytag" sort="list" decorator="checkboxDecorator" excludedParams="_chk" id="itemName" >
                <display:setProperty name="basic.empty.showtable" value="true"  />

                <%// <display:column  property="id" title="ID" ></display:column> %>
                <display:column  property="occid" title="Occupant ID"  ></display:column>
                <display:column  title="Check" headerClass="sortable">
                    <input type="radio"  id="check" name="check" value="${itemName.occid}" />
                </display:column>
                <display:column  property="firstName" title="First Name" ></display:column>
                <display:column  property="lastName" title="Last Name"   ></display:column>
                <display:column  property="sonOf" title="Father's Name"  ></display:column>
                <display:column  property="district" title="District"  ></display:column>
                <display:column  property="village" title="Village"  ></display:column>

              </display:table>
            </p>
            <p>
              <input type="submit" name="EDIT" id="EDIT" value="EDIT" onClick="javascript:checkModify();">
            </p>
```

Comment: somebody please answer its urgent.

Answer (score 1):

try doing uid_rowNum so in your case it would be itemName_rowNum.